# Does Anyone Have Recordings of Tunisian Te'amim

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, trop-cantillation

Does Anyone Have Recordings of Tunisian Te'amim, or know of a website that has them?

Comment: Any chance this can be made into a more general question with a wiki answer listing many different customs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are recordings of the Tunisian Te'amim according to a few different chazzanim

http://www.rebbihaitaieblomet.org/cours-enseignements/taamims/article/taamimes-de-la-torah-par-benjamin